# How to use jquery in GTM without impacting another instance of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I want to call an http request via ajax from within a GTM (Google Tag Manager) tag.  My question is how to prevent conflicts between the instance of jquery that will load within the GTM tag and an instance that may load elsewhere.

My understanding is that the noconflict method can only be used after the second jquery instance has loaded and run, but since GTM is asynchronous I have no control over which instance will load first.

To further complicate matters, my GTM tag is being called from another website (live site) over which I have no control, and which I do not want to impact.

Here is an example of the code I want to run with my GTM tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type"text/javascript">
    var logUrl = "https://example.com/log.php";
    var logData = "some data that I want to log";
    var parmData = {Data: logData};
    $.ajax({
             async: true,
             url: logUrl,
             data: parmData,
             type: "POST",
    });
</script>
```

Please advise how I can use the noconflict menthod (or any other control) to ensure that there are no adverse effects on the other site from my use of jquery in my GTM tag.

Comment: you might use plain XMLHTTPRequest or fetch() to make your requests. In that way, you're don't need to care for any instances and most importantly you don't need to load anything.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example_POST

Comment: @ДмитроБулах that's a great idea.  I've been reading up a little on XMLHTTPRequest.  I would want to pass the full url of the current page as a parameter: can I just use JSON.stringify(window.location.href)?

Comment: you can use just simply window.location.href

Comment: @ДмитроБулах so then I should encode the url - encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) ?  I ask because most of the coding examples for XMLHTTPRequest use encoding.  Also, would you use a synchronous call or async, bearing in mind that GTM is already asynchronous to the user?

Comment: encoding and specific formatting for the request data are server-specific, please check the docs of the server behind your logUrl